# Copy childs of one movieclip to another movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i have two movieclips container.

MovieClip_1
MovieClip_2

now MovieClip_1 contains one child _child_1. now by pressing button i want to add that _child_1 of MovieClip_1 to MovieClip_2 without removing from MovieClip_1.

i tried following code in button press event but it removes _child_1 from its past container.

```
var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(MovieClip_1.getChildAt(0));
MovieClip_2.addChild(mc);
```

Comment: How was _child_1 added to MovieClip_1 in the first place? Was it added in the autoring tool or did you add it through `getDefinitionByName(..)`?

Comment: _child_1 is a movieclip, i am adding it through MovieClip_1.addChild(_child_1);

Comment: How do you create _child_1? Basically what I'm trying to get at is that you can probably use the same creation mechanism you use to create _child_1 and add it to MovieClip_1, to add a new instance of _child_1 to MovieClip_2

Comment: _child_1 is a library attached movieclip

Comment: Then can't you just create a new instance from the library and attach it to MovieClip_2? If you need to preserve scale, rotation, position etc, it'd be trivial to make a "clone" function for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to add the same display object to two different parents. Trying to do so will remove the display object from its former parent.

Instead, consider creating a new instance of your child's class and add this instance to the container MovieClip_2.

Comment: Thanx for the answer but how to create new instance of movieclip child, is it possible with getChildAt()???

Comment: 1. yes, `getChildAt()` gives you the child. 2. `Object(child).constructor` gives you the class of the child. 3. Create an instance of that class, this will be a copy of the child. 4. Add it to MovieClip_2.

Answer (score 2):

What Jens said is correct. There is however a class for copying DisplayObjects. Check out 
http://www.senocular.com/flash/actionscript/?file=ActionScript_3.0/com/senocular/display/duplicateDisplayObject.as.