# duplicate movieclip and sound on-off

Tags: actionscript-3, code-conversion

```
on (press) {
    i = i + 1;
    duplicateMovieClip (_root.circle, "circle" + i, i);
}
```

how to use that code in flash as3 coding and please give me some example or link,  how to create duplicate movieclip in as3 ?And please tell me how to play/pouse one particular sound in flash as3 ?

Comment: Just posted: Duplicate movie clip http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911746/copy-childs-of-one-movieclip-to-another-movieclip/6911935#6911935

Answer (score 0):

Jens Struwe posted a link as a comment, it will help you with the duplicateMovieClip problem.

When you start playing a sound with `mySound.play()` it returns a `SoundChannel`-object, grab a reference to it and then use `mySoundChannel.stop()` to stop the playback. Also when you stop the sound playback, use `var myStopPosition:Number = mySoundChannel.position` to find out where you stopped. Then pass that position to `mySound.play(myStopPosition)` when you want to resume playback.